# How to prevent duplicate URL concatenation after redirect?

Tags: jsp, url, tomcat, servlets

I wrote a page called login.jsp (tomcat6) which has a login form (username, password etc).

I've mapped the form action and servlet so the form submission results in invocation of login servlet.

**1. login.jsp has a form which invokes the servlet.**

```
<form name="login_form" action="servlet/login" method="POST">
```

**2. servlet mapping in deployment descriptor (web.xml)**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletLogin</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.masatosan.loginservlet.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletLogin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So, from the jsp page, when a user clicks on login button, the servlet (LoginServlet.class) takes care of the login business.

When login fails from a mismatched password and such, the servlet redirects the user back to login page.

code snippet from LoginServlet.class

```
String address = "home.jsp"
if(hasError) {
   address = "register.jsp"
}
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(address);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

**Problem:**

It works great for the first request.

1. Provide invalid credentials (bad username or password) to login form.
2. hasError flag is set to true and redirects me back to the login page (with URL changed from **localhost:8080/login.jsp** to **localhost:8080/servlet/login**)

I'm happy so far, but not after what follows.

3. Provide invalid credential to login form again.

**Result:**

Now I get HTTP 404 and URL is: **localhost:8080/servlet/servlet/login**
(with extra "servlet")

The solution I'm looking for is to redirect to the original login page when I redirect a user due to login failure. Is it possible to redirect to login.jsp OR not having extra "servlet" text in URL which causes the 404?

NOTE: The online tutorial I read mentions not including "servlet" in url mapping like I did `<url-pattern>/servlet/login</url-pattern>` but the jsp host I have forces me to do so (mount directive) due a requirement to to distinguish php and other things. :(

**UPDATE:**

I found this on the net, have not tested yet but will update...

```
response.sendRedirect(LOGIN_PAGE);
```

**Solution**

The sendRedirect approach was not what I wanted. I needed to forward a request/response via dispatcher but sendRedirect only takes a response as an argument.

The trick to the original question was to use absolute path in form as suggested.
My fix which worked is:

```
(login.jsp)
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
%>

<form name="login_form" action="<%= path %>/servlet/login" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the absolute path to `ServletLogin` in your form definition in `login.jsp`:

```
<form name="login_form" action="/servlet/login" method="POST">
```